# Attempting to test rest service with multipart file

Tags: spring, rest

I am attempting to test a rest service I created. The service is a post.

1. I wanted to create a file to pass the parameters(including a multi-part file).
2. From there I am trying to call the service at this point.

Pretty sure the service that doesn't work. But when I call rest Service.  I have a simple form that just passes in a couple values including the jpg.

Here is the code.

```
HttpMessageConverter bufferedIamageHttpMessageConverter =   new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/sendScreeenAsPostCard",  uploadItem.getFileData(),  String.class));
```

My method signature is:

```
ResultStatus sendScreenAsPostcard( @RequestParam MultipartFile image, @RequestParamString userId)
```

That is the error I am getting.

> `Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]`

Answer (score 10):

You need to simulate a file upload, which requires a particular content type header, body parameters, etc. Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Fill out the "form"...
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parameters.add("file", new FileSystemResource("file.jpg")); // load file into parameter
parameters.add("blah", blah); // some other form field

// Set the headers...
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); // we are sending a form
headers.set("Accept", "text/plain"); // looks like you want a string back

// Fire!
String result = restTemplate.exchange(
    "http://localhost:8080/sendScreeenAsPostCard",
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers),
    String.class
).getBody();
```

Comment: Ok, I think I might be making some progress thanks to you. I am getting a 404 error which I think could be related to my post method's signature?

Comment: It looks like you are using Spring MVC with annotations, so I expect your `sendScreenAsPostcard` method should have something like `@RequestMapping(method=POST, value="/sendScreeenAsPostCard")` on it. Then depending on web.xml, container behavior, etc. there might be something before your endpoint (ex. Tomcat by default wants the WAR name right after the host/port). Also there are 3 e's in your method - 404 due to typo? Lastly, when Spring loads and things are configured correctly, you should see it log all the endpoints it thinks it is exposing so you can verify.

Comment: Allthree of your points have been EXTRAORDINARILY helpful. Now I am getting a 406 error. My spelling was wrong and I have changed my parameters in my call so much thinking that was the problem. Here is the signature. I was getting a 406 Error and the current error I am receiving is 500. @RequestMapping(value = "/sendScreenAsPostcard", method = { RequestMethod.POST })

Comment: I get it to work if I have the method only use sendScreenAsPostcard(HttpServletRequest request) but unable to get values.

Comment: I looked at my own file upload that uses `@RequestParam`s - each of my parameters names the parameter from the HTTP form, for example: `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("userId") String userId` (note the HTTP names in quotes). Perhaps try that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works great and allows a lot of flexibility in request customization. Btw, it works on android too.