# Spring - RestTemplate - Multipart File

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipart

This controller works fine

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
....
@PostMapping("/convert")
public void fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Now i want to call this controller from another spring project via RestTemplate. I tried many things, but noting works. Here is my last code:

```
@Controller
public class FileController {
....
@PostMapping("/convert")
public void fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


    ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>(
            Arrays.asList(new FormHttpMessageConverter(),new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(), new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()));

    RestTemplate template = restTemplate();

    template.setMessageConverters(converters);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    multipartRequest.add("file", file);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartRequest, header);

    template.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/convert", requestEntity, String.class);

}
```

I if call FileUploadController (via postman) it works. If if call FileController
i get this Exception

```
"exception": 
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
"message": "Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile]",
"path": "/convert"
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the answer here, it should be exactly what you are looking for: [Attempting to test rest service with multipart file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003045/attempting-to-test-rest-service-with-multipart-file)

The issue there is about posting a multi-part file to a rest service using a `RestTemplate`.

Basically, what you have to do is to simulate a file upload. You can try something like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parameters.add("file", new FileSystemResource("file.jpg"));

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
headers.set("Accept", "text/plain");

String result = restTemplate.postForObject(
    "http://host:port/path", 
    new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers), 
    String.class);
```

Comment: Can you also provide how this issue is related to the one you posted. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for community guidelines

Comment: @harshavmb DONE

Comment: The only difference to my code "is parameters.add("file", new FileSystemResource("file.jpg"));". instead of "multipartRequest.add("file", file);". If i change my code in this way the request is delivered to the first controller. Great! But now i become an exception regarding the response "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String]".....

Comment: It might be that your client is not able to understand the response type received by the server. 
Since the response you're expecting is a simple String, try to add the response type to the `@PostMapping` notation as follows:

`@PostMapping(path="/convert", produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)`