# Spring Boot RestTemplate Timing Out when uploading large file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am developing a web service that will accept and filter a stream of json data. To test my code I am reading json from a file, but the RestTemplate connection is timing out when the file is more than 2.5MB. I'd like to know why this isn't working, and if there is a better way to do this

```
    String requestUrl = "http://localhost:" + port + "/v1/filterLarge";

    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
    RequestCallback requestCallback = (ClientHttpRequest request) -> {
        request.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        IOUtils.copy(is, request.getBody());
    };

    ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = (ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) -> {
        InputStream inputStream = clientHttpResponse.getBody();
        try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Development\\bags.json"))) {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, os);
        }
        return null;
    };

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    restTemplate.execute(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
```

This is my server side code:

```
@PostMapping(value="/filterLarge")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> filterLarge(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException  {
    StreamFilter streamFilter = new StreamFilter();
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache()).body(
            (OutputStream outputStream) -> 
                streamFilter.filter(is, outputStream)
            );      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said you're uploading a file but actually you're just sending the file content in the request body directly. So you need to change your client code to actually do a file upload (i.e. multipart request). You can find a sample implementation in several SO answers, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003045/attempting-to-test-rest-service-with-multipart-file). You need to do it this way because large POST request bodies, while possible, are not recommended for security reasons.

Now, once you've done the above, change the below properties ([reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)) to increase the default accepted limits.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=<Size>
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=<Size>
```

Or if you still want to go with your client implementation unchanged, change the below property depending on the server you use (default in boot is tomcat) to increase the POST limit. The default size for tomcat is 2 MB.

```
server.<Server>.max-http-post-size=<Size-In-Bytes>
```

Where `<Server>` can be "tomcat" or "jetty" or whatever you use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In reality the json will not be read from a file, I am using the file for testing purposes only. I am aware of multipart file uploads and I have used this approach before but this is not what I am trying to accomplish here. Your reply has been very informative though. Could you elaborate on the security issue you mentioned?

Comment: Servers restrict POST body size out of the box to avoid denial-of-service attacks. From tomcat's [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html): *The maxPostSize attribute controls the maximum size of a POST request that will be parsed for parameters. The parameters are cached for the duration of the request so this is limited to 2MB by default to reduce exposure to a DOS attack.*. A user could maliciously post a huge request and overload server memory. Of course, this isn't the only config  parameter - it's used in combination with timeouts and other limits to avoid DOS.

Comment: BTW, if you absolutely want to go with large JSON in POST body, you can still use the last part of my answer to increase the limit.